# Is there a way to export Macros from MobaXterm

Tags: windows, mobaxterm

Hi I'm using MobaXterm v12.1 and would like to export the macros I created from my laptop to another one.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I would like to export the MobaXterm macros I created from my laptop.

The macros are stored in the `MobaXterm.ini` file in your MobaXterm directory.

There is a section labelled `[Macros]`

You can either copy the whole file to your other PC, or just copy the `[Macros]` and edit into the `MobaXterm.ini` on the other PC.

Answer (score 0):

From the sidebar, there is a '**Macros**' vertical tab. [Macros Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7oV3.png)

When you click on it, it displays all your recorded macros.
Right-click on the list gives you import/export options.

Hope it could help.